# How to give a overlay for a grid element with Canvas.ZIndex = 5 in UWP

Tags: uwp, xbox

I am trying to open a full screen popup using a collapsed Grid  from  a frame and its working but would like to have overlay for the grid to give a popup effect. How can I achieve that?

Comment: this is probably ur 3rd question on just the same problem, and to be honest this popup effect for a normal grid can be too complicated for you bcz u r new to the platform.

Comment: also u need to provide the frame and grid code so that others can understand what is the context of your question, I understand it bcz i knw abt ur issue but others dont.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have done. Besides, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will help you improve the quality of your question, then other commubity members will be happy to help you.